# error Type 'null' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538) in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```js
onClick() {
  let obj = {
    fName: "ali",
    LName: "sarabi",
    age: "19",
  }
  let fieldName = prompt("field");
  alert(obj[fieldName]);
}
```

I write this code and it has error in `alert(obj[fieldName])`
it has error on **fieldName**:

**let fieldName: string | null
Type 'null' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)**

how can I fix it??

Comment: Did you try `let fieldName ?: string` and remove `null` from type?

Comment: Remember that users can cancel a prompt. `fieldName` is guaranteed to sometimes _not_ be a value. Also, don't use `alert` unless something's gone horribly wrong, it's a thread-blocking operation. Use console.log if you just want to see things working for yourself, or you just need data to end up somewhere for debug/posting purposes, or properly update your page instead of triggering a full page interrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**
Typescript is a strict typed language so it will error at compile time when you use `prompt()` returned value as an index.
Because array index cannot be null, but `prompt()` return value can be null.
So you have to tell the compiler if `fieldName` was null use an empty string. This way compiler make sure that index won't be null ever!

Try this:

```js
onClick(){
    let obj={
      fName:"ali",
      LName:"sarabi",
      age:"19",
    }
    let fieldName = prompt("field") || "";
    alert(obj[fieldName]);
}
```

or this:

```js
onClick(){
    let obj={
      fName:"ali",
      LName:"sarabi",
      age:"19",
    }
    let fieldName = prompt("field");
    alert(obj[fieldName?fieldName:""]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

before alert, you have to check whether `fieldName` is set or not

add this condition :

```
if(fieldName !== null) {
// alert(obj[fieldName])}
```